# Moose Perl: "modify multiple methods in all subclasses"

Tags: perl, methods, moose, method-modifier

I have a Moose BaseDBModel which has different subclasses mapping to my tables in the database. All the methods in the subclasses are like "get_xxx" or "update_xxx" which refers to the different DB operations.

Now i want to implement a cache system for all these methods, so my idea is "before" all methods named like "get_xxx", I will search the name of the method as key in my memcache pool for value. If i found the value, then I will return the value directly instead of method.

ideally, my code is like this

BaseDBModel

```
package Speed::Module::BaseDBModel;
use Moose;
sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;

  for my $method ($self->meta->get_method_list()){
    if($method =~ /^get_/){
      $self->meta->add_before_method_modifier($method,sub {
        warn $method;
        find_value_by_method_name($method);
        [return_value_if_found_value]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

SubClasses Example 1

```
package Speed::Module::Character;
use Moose;

extends 'Speed::Module::BaseDBModel';
method get_character_by_id {
    xxxx
}
```

Now my problem is that when my program is running, it's repeatedly modify the methods, for example:

1. restart apache
2. visit the page which will call get_character_by_id, so I can see one warning message

Codes:

```
my $db_character = Speed::Module::Character->new(glr => $self->glr);
$character_state = $db_character->get_character_by_id($cid);
```

Warnings:

```
get_character_by_id at /Users/dyk/Sites/speed/lib/Speed/Module/BaseDBModel.pm line 60.
```

but if I refresh the page, I saw 2 warning messages

Warnings:

```
get_character_by_id at /Users/dyk/Sites/speed/lib/Speed/Module/BaseDBModel.pm line 60.
get_character_by_id at /Users/dyk/Sites/speed/lib/Speed/Module/BaseDBModel.pm line 60.
```

I am using mod_perl 2.0 with apache, every time i refresh the page, my get_character_by_id method will be modified which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your BUILD doing the add_before every time you construct a new instance? I'm not sure that's what you want.

---

Well, the simple/clunky way would be to set some package-level flag so you only do it once.

Otherwise, I think you want to hook into Moose's own attribute building. Have a look at this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=948231

Comment: that is not I want, I only want to modify the "before" once

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `BUILD` runs every time your create an *object* (i.e. after every `->new()` call), but `add_before_method_modifier` adds modifier to *class*, i.e. to *all objects*.

### Simple solution

Mind, that `use` calls [import](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) function from used package every time. That is the place where you want to add modifiers.

Parent:

```
package Parent;

use Moose;

sub import {
    my ($class) = @_;

    foreach my $method ($class->meta->get_method_list) {
        if ($method =~ /^get_/) {
            $class->meta->add_before_method_modifier($method, sub {
                warn $method
            });
        }
    }
}

1;
```

Child1:

```
package Child1;

use Moose;
extends 'Parent';

sub get_a { 'a' }

1;
```

Child2:

```
package Child2;

use Moose;
extends 'Parent';

sub get_b { 'b' }

1;
```

So now it works as expected:

```
$ perl -e 'use Child1; use Child2; Child1->new->get_a; Child2->new->get_b; Child1->new->get_a;'
get_a at Parent.pm line 11.
get_b at Parent.pm line 11.
get_a at Parent.pm line 11.
```

### Cleaner solution

Since you can't be 100% sure `import` will be called (since you can't be sure `use` will be used) the more cleaner and straightforward solution is just add something like `use My::Getter::Cacher` in every derived class.

```
package My::Getter::Cacher;

sub import {
    my $class = [caller]->[0];

    # ...
}
```

In this case every derived class should contain both `extends 'Parent'` and `use My::Getter::Cacher` since the first line is about inheritance while the second is about adding before modifier. You may count it a bit redundant, but as I said I believe it's more cleaner and straightforward.

### P. S.

Maybe you should give a glance at [Memoize](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html) module.